# Abstract test method error when printing arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract

I have created an Employee class used to figure by weekly pay as an abstract. I have then created 2 subclasses for Salary and Hourly employees. The issue I have is in my test class not printing out the array list and then retrieving the correct bi weekly pay. Was hopping another set of eyes could help.

```
/** Employee class with abstract method*/
public abstract class Employee {

public String fullName;

/** construct a default employee object*/
public Employee() {
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

/** abstract method getBIWeeklyPay */
public abstract double getBiWeeklyPay(); 
public void printgetBiWeeklPay() {
   System.out.println("Employee "+this.fullName+ "'s"+ "Bi-weekly pay is:");
}   

}
/**Salary Class*/
public class SalaryEmployee extends Employee {


public SalaryEmployee() {
}

public double salary;

public double getBiWeeklyPay() {
    return salary/(52*2) ;

}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
 }
/** Hourly Class*/
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {

public double hourlyRate;
public double hoursPerWeek;


public HourlyEmployee() {
}

public double getBiWeeklyPay() {
    return hourlyRate * (hoursPerWeek *2);
}

public double getHourlyRate() {
    return hourlyRate;
}

public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRate) {
    this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
}

public double getHoursPerWeek() {
    return hoursPerWeek;
}

public void setHoursPerWeek(double hoursPerWeek) {
    this.hoursPerWeek = hoursPerWeek;
}   
}
 /**Test Class*/

  import java.util.*;

  public class EmployeeTest {

public static void main(String[] args){

ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

SalaryEmployee mike = new SalaryEmployee();
mike.setFullName("Mike Burns");
mike.setSalary(75000.00);
employees.add(mike);

HourlyEmployee tim = new HourlyEmployee();
tim.setFullName("Tim Globe");
tim.setHourlyRate(12.00);
tim.setHoursPerWeek(40.00);
employees.add(tim);
print(employees);

}
 public static void print(ArrayList<Employee> employees){   
    for(Employee e: employees){
      e.printgetBiWeeklyPay();
}
}

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure `ArrayList` doesn't have a `printBiWeeklyPay()` method...

Comment: Yes, There are 2 errors, it doesnt like the Main method in the test, it gets an exception of some kind, and then it cannot resolve the print.BiWeeklyPay(); to the array list even tho it should belong to the abstract and each other method (salary/hourly).

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific than `it doesn't like the Main method` and *especially* for "it gets an exception of some kind".

Comment: The code doesn't even compile in the first place, because ArrayList doesn't have a printBiWeeklyPay function

Comment: I need it to print the employees names and the biweekly pay they should get based upon the info I enter to be stored into the array.

Comment: Then you need to print the names of the **employees**, not the **arraylist**.

Comment: I may be confused but if it doesnt print the array list then how will it assign the other variables entered (type of employee, pay, hours, etc)to the list and then to the specific methods.

Comment: If you want to print data about employees, you have to print the employees themselves. Not the `ArrayList` containing them.

Comment: @user3580294 Ok, but in order to print out the data I would have to call the elements individually. I was under the impression that there was a way to make the arraylist info move to the classes and be run via the methods and called with 1 simple method. Maybe I am over thinking this or maybe I am still a bit to green.

Comment: You're right that you'd have to call the elements individually. There's no way to automatically call a method on all the elements of a list at once, but what you *can* do is *iterate* over the elements of the list, as the given answer does.

Comment: Yes, however I would have to stray for the UML requirements. And I was told by another person it could be done similar to this pseudo code. Shown below.

Comment: Can you post the Logcat or stack trace where the exception is?

Answer (score 1):

your var employees is of type ArrayList but ArrayList has no printBiWeeklyPay function.

instead you should make your own printBiWeeklyPay function that takes the ArrayList as a parameter and call that instead.

An example would be:

```
public void printByWeeklyPay(ArrayList<Employee> list) {
    for (Employee e : list) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Also you'll have to override #toString() in your Employee classes to return some relevant output.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(john); // hourly employee
employees.add(fred); // salary employee
employees.add(bob);  //hourly employee
print(employees);
}

public static void print(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
   for each employee in employees {
       employee.printBiWeeklyPay();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what the given answer does... Iterates over the employees in the list and prints each one of them. You'd have to define a `printBiWeeklyPay()` method for the type `Employee` though.

Comment: Well, if you want to **print**BiWeeklyPay(), you'd need something that would print, right?

Comment: :) yes, silly me I now have a System.out.print() statement as part of that method. However since the print statement is in the "Employee' Class and that is where the abstract is for 'getBiWeeklyPay' how get it to pull from the employees specific type of pay IE Salary or Hourly. FYI I did go back and make them all the same, I notice I used getBiweeklyPay in the sper and subclasses, So I now have made that cahnge.

Comment: If I'm understanding things right, your overridden `getBiWeeklyPay()` should take care of salary/hourly

Comment: Yes it should but I cannot seem to call it in the print statement, so when  call the print method in the test it wont pull the calculation. I will update all the code from my initial post.

Comment: Is it because I have no setter for that in each employee type?

Comment: What happens if you try? Is there a compiler error?

Comment: No compiler error, it just returns only what is now in the print statement but wont actually calculate the bi weekly pay. So my output is... Employee John Doe's bi-weekly pay is:

Comment: You forgot to tack on the output from `getBiWeeklyPay()`

Comment: ?? Not sure I follow, there isnt an output in the Employee class since its an abstract.

Comment: For `printGetBiWeeklyPay()`, you need to add in the output from `getBiWeeklyPay()`

Comment: Ok but the output varies depending on which class it runs through. so i cant just put getBiWeeklyPay or it tells me its undefined

Comment: You *should* be able to. That's one of the advantages of inheritance -- polymorphism. `getBiWeeklyPay()` may be `abstract` in `Employee`, but each of your concrete classes that `extend Employee` should override it, so in the end you get a working `getBiWeeklyPay()`

Comment: @user3580294 Thank you so much, it now works. Boy I feel stupid, i for got the () afterward so thats why it was throwing my error. Thanks for all you help and patience.

Comment: No problem! Glad that I could help. Hope things are smooth sailing from here on out.